# MongoDb: I want to return all of the values from an array that appear more than once. Not sure how to go about this

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
[
  {
    "postsWith": [
      "postid1",
      "postid2",
      "postid3"
    ],
    "name": "hashtag1",
  },
 {
    "postsWith": [
      "postid4",
      "postid5",
      "postid6"
    ],
    "name": "hashtag2",
  },
 {
    "postsWith": [
      "postid2"
    ],
    "name": "hashtag3",
  }
]
```

I want to be able to search for the duplicate post ids in 'hashtag1' and 'hashtag3'

which should return 'postid2'

is this possible ?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? if so, can you approve?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using grouping and counting

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h9CzMYuGNG_)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {//Reshape the array
    $unwind: "$postsWith"
  },
  {//Group and get the count
    $group: {
      "_id": "$postsWith",
      "sum": {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {//Definitely you can combine project and the following match
    $project: {
      "duplicate": {
        $cond: {
          if: {//Just adding a flag
            $gt: [
              "$sum",
              1
            ]
          },
          then: 1,
          else: 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {//returning only duplicate
      duplicate: 1
    }
  }
])
```